# Passing a class variable into a method

Tags: python-3.x, class

I'm trying to build a class in python 3 and I'm having trouble understanding how to call a variable into a method from a variable in the **init** function

I've googled the issue for a few hours with no luck. I must not be looking under the right pretext.

Here is the test code.

```
import numpy as np

trade_data = np.ones((20, 6))


    
class Stuff():
    

    def __init__(self, period, period_division): 

        self.period_division = period_division
        self.period = period
        
        max_equity = self.stuff_max_equity(period)
        
        self.max_equity_value = 0

        things = (1+1)                             
        oter_things = (1+1)


    def stuff_max_equity(self,period):


        for n in range(period):
            i =1
            if trade_data[i,5] > self.max_equity_value:
                self.max_equity_value = trade_data[i,5]

                return self.max_equity_value

            else:

                return self.max_equity_value
```

The above code gives me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c63eef3f275e> in <module>
----> 1 Stuff(5,1)

<ipython-input-10-6e91341fd770> in __init__(self, period, period_division)
     13         self.period = period
     14 
---> 15         max_equity = self.stuff_max_equity(period)
     16 
     17         self.max_equity_value = 0

<ipython-input-10-6e91341fd770> in stuff_max_equity(self, period)
     26         for n in range(period):
     27             i = 1
---> 28             if trade_data[i,5] > self.max_equity_value:
     29                 self.max_equity_value = trade_data[i,5]
     30 

AttributeError: 'Stuff' object has no attribute 'max_equity_value'
```

I've tried replacing self.max_equity_value  with max_equity_value and some other things but I get the same error.

How do I properly pass this variable into the method?

Appreciated

Comment: The problem is that you're only creating/assigning the `max_equity_value` attribute **after** you call the `stuff_max_equity`  function (which requires that attribute to exist beforehand).

Comment: How is the `stuff_max_equity` function meant to work, exactly? You're seemingly using its return-value to set an attribute, but the function is apparently _dependent_ on that attribute - which means it cannot safely run.

Comment: Aha! So in other words, swap the self.max_equity_value = 0 and the max_equity = self.stuff_max_equity(period).
It was so obvious. Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suggest you start using a step-through debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Promoting my comment to an answer:</sub>

The problem is that you're only creating/assigning the `max_equity_value` attribute **after** you call the `stuff_max_equity` function.

Assuming that `0` as an initial value for `max_equity_value` is correct, then change this:

```py
    def __init__(self, period, period_division): 

        self.period_division = period_division
        self.period = period
        
        max_equity = self.stuff_max_equity(period)
        
        self.max_equity_value = 0

        things = (1+1)                             
        oter_things = (1+1)
```

...to this:

```py
    def __init__(self, period, period_division): 

        self.period_division = period_division
        self.period = period

        self.max_equity_value = 0
        
        max_equity = self.stuff_max_equity(period)
        
        things = (1+1)                             
        oter_things = (1+1)
```

*That said*, your program might be easier to follow if you instead make `stuff_max_equity` a `@staticmethod` and pass `max_equity_value` in as an explicit parameter, that way there's no non-obvious state mutations.